# R: adding multiple regression lines and loess curve to plot

Tags: r, regression

```
mod = lm(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Width + iris$Species)
plot(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Width, col = iris$Species)
abline(mod)
```

[image]

Here I'm stratifying `Species` and I want to plot 3 regression lines, one for each species. `abline(mod)` seems to only add one line only. Also, what if I wanted to add LOESS curve?

Comment: You want this in base plot rather than ggplot, which makes this sort of thing super easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ggplot one-liner:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, color=Species)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~x)
```

Leave out the arguments to `geom_smooth()` and you would get the LOESS line. However, the data here are so scant that this fails.

Answer (score 2):

```
mod = lm(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Width + iris$Species)
plot(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Width, col = iris$Species)
abline(coefficients(mod)[1], coefficients(mod)[2])
abline(coefficients(mod)[1], coefficients(mod)[3])
abline(coefficients(mod)[1], coefficients(mod)[4])
```